# Извлечь буквы и цифры из переменной типа String по отдельности

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть переменная `String message = "23.02.2009 ДОЛЛАР США";`
Хотел бы записать `"23.02.2009"` отдельно в `String number;` и соответственно `"ДОЛЛАР США"` в `String string;` 
И цифры с учетом точек. Реально ли с помощью регулярных выражений реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

> Реально ли с помощью регулярных выражений реализовать?

Почему бы и нет? Регулярки для подобных задачи и были созданы:

```
String message = "23.02.2009 ДОЛЛАР США";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}\\.\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}) (.+)");
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(message);
if (m.find()) {
    String number = m.group(1);
    String string = m.group(2);
    System.out.println(number);  // 23.02.2009
    System.out.println(string);  // ДОЛЛАР США
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Не регулярные выражения, но можно и так. Думаю если почитать подробнее про `StringTokenizer` и `String.split` то можно, что-то интересное найти.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class Split {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "23.02.2009 ДОЛЛАР США";
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(message, " ");
        String numbers = tokenizer.nextToken();
        String words = tokenizer.nextToken() + " " + tokenizer.nextToken();
        System.out.println(numbers + '\n' + words);
    }
}
```